# ASP.Net MVC 3 Grids

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, telerik, asp.net-mvc-3

I see that there is the Telerik Grid, jqGrid and WebHelper WebGrid as part of the framework.  Am I missing any others?

Which one works best on a commercial application with thousands of rows and master/detail relationships for ASP.Net MVC 3?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Telerik MVC grid in production. Take a look at the grid at [an online Diamond store](http://bit.ly/hgfC6D). It works the same with even 50k+ rows as it only sends the current page to the browser + it has many cool features like Filters, Ajax binding etc.
No idea on the master details front. You could find more info about it [on Telerik's Site](http://bit.ly/dy9eg6)

Answer (score 0):

there is also grid supplied by mvccontrib. I personally use telerik grid having some cool features and scale for large data Q3 2010 has some good improvements such as inline editing etc. For MVC 3 grid i am waiting for rtm of mvc 3 coming in January

Comment: I have looked at the Telerik grid and jqGrid at heirarchical demos but it just looks very webforms like and overcomplicated. Telerik do produce good stuff but something doesn't feel right about the way they implement these master/details grids

Comment: Yes their code looks somewhat complex but these are the only options that i have seen so for another grid that you may look is http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/ but you have to buy

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Telerik for a commercial project, then you will need to buy it. Check this link: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/licensing.aspx.

We're using the jQuery in our [project](http://xenta.net), so the jqGrid is most suitable for us. It's powerfull, has a lot of plugins and completely free, but little bit more complicated in use than Telerik.

jqGrid usage example:

- [view] 
  http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11214#118453
- [controller]
  http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/11214#118416

Comment: I believe jqGrid is not free, otherwise why would they have license plans? You can check it [here](http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx)

Comment: It's your choice in what to believe. But jqGrid is released under GPL and MIT licenses. They have the commercial components(ASP.NET, PHP) which you have mentioned, but the base component(JS, CSS, etc.) is available for free. Check this link http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=154.

Comment: Actually i've just read where this misconception was made. It seems that they have 2 products whose names are "jqGrid PlugIn" and "jqGrid". The latter is paid, the previous is not. I got confused when you said that jqGrid was free, so i decided to search a little more. You can find a nice comment about this[here] (http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=639#comment-9824).